# Lightswitch: does the arrow over tilde represent "common" and how should it be wired

Tags: lighting

This question relates to wiring a dimmer switch.

[image: switch back photo]

What does the symbol next to L2 represent? I assume from looking at other switches that this is the "common" connection.

Should i wire the switch as follows:

[image: This is how i intend to wire the switch]

Comment: Read the dimmer switch's datasheet.

Comment: Dimmer switch did not come with a datasheet, that was the first place i looked.

Comment: So, did you check online for the data sheet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it ought to be on DIY Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT wire it that way.

[This PDF shows the proper way to wire that type of dimmer.](https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Technical/DataSheets/Varilight/V-Dim_H_Dimmer_Instructions_554.pdf)

**Single dimmer switch:**

[image]

**Dimmer with a second switch:**

[image]

Comment: So is the tilde arrow symbol common? Figure 2 looks like what im after and what i proposed.

Comment: Your diagram seems to show ground going to L2.  The "tilde" is a representation of AC, and the arrow means it is variable.

Comment: the ground is a separate connection, thats  just bad diagram drawing.

Comment: + to JRE, it is not a common symbol but I have seen it a few times in the past. It is common to see an arrow through a resistor , capacitor or coil to show it is variable.

Answer (score 0):

L1 and L2 are "Line 1" and "Line 2" (so HOT and NEUTRAL of the AC line). The tilde with the arrow through it symbolizes the adjusted AC. This is the HOT OUT (the dimmed output). Connect the light between the adjusted AC output and Neutral.